# Retrieve Records of the Last Consecutive Dates in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, gaps-and-islands

**Edit** Sorry for being unclear in the first post. If the item appears only **once**, it should also be **included**. Please, check **updated** sample table...

I have a table of record of sales of each item per day. A candidate key for this table would be the combination of item_id and date. What I'm trying to get is a view of all records from the last (latest) consecutive dates of each item. If the item only appear once, it should also be included.

What I have

```
+---------+------------+------------+
| item_id |    date    | gross_sale |
|  (text) |   (date)   |  (double)  |
+---------+------------+------------+
| 11aa    | 2019-01-01 |         45 |
| 11aa    | 2019-01-02 |         85 |
| 22bb    | 2019-01-01 |         65 |
| 22bb    | 2019-01-02 |         15 |
| 22bb    | 2019-01-03 |         45 |
| 11aa    | 2019-01-05 |         32 |
| 33cc    | 2019-01-05 |         11 |
| 22bb    | 2019-01-05 |         23 |
| 22bb    | 2019-01-06 |         56 |
| 11aa    | 2019-01-06 |         78 |
| 11aa    | 2019-01-07 |         12 |
| 11aa    | 2019-01-08 |         45 |
+---------+------------+------------+
```

What I want

```
+---------+------------+------------+
| item_id |    date    | gross_sale |
+---------+------------+------------+
| 11aa    | 2019-01-05 |         32 |
| 11aa    | 2019-01-06 |         78 |
| 11aa    | 2019-01-07 |         12 |
| 11aa    | 2019-01-08 |         45 |
| 22bb    | 2019-01-05 |         23 |
| 22bb    | 2019-01-06 |         56 |
| 33cc    | 2019-01-05 |         11 |
+---------+------------+------------+
```

I read from several post that it can simply be done using CTE and window but I'm still quite new to them. If you don't mind, could you please include a small explanation on how your code works too?

Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can enumerate the rows and add an increasing sequence starting from the *end* of the data

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by item_id order by date desc) as seqnum,
             max(date) over (partition by item_id) as max_date
      from t
     ) t
where date + (seqnum - 1) * interval '1 day' = max_date
```

Comment: I know I'm not supposed to say this as a comment. I'm quite new to the partition concept too so it took me a while to understand how the code works but now that I understand it, I really found this as a very clever solution. I did learn a lot from this code, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

no need for cte, you can use this simple query.

```
select distinct t1.item_id, t1.maxdate, t2.gross_sale from 
    (select item_id, max(date) as maxdate from table1 group by item_id) as t1
left join table1 t2 on t2.item_id= t1.maxdate and t1.item_id=t2.item_id
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it via correlated subquery to check difference of dates of a particular item_id

```
       SELECT ITEM_ID, DATE, 
       GROSS_SALE FROM TABLE  X
         Where Item_Id In (Select 
          Item_id from table t where 
         abs(t.Date-X.Date)=1)
        Order 
       by Item_id asc, Date desc
```